# How to replace request date with a variable extract from Combobox value in powerapps

Tags: vba, mobile-application, powerapps

How to replace request date with a variable extract from Combobox value

Below code working

```
Sort(Filter(Install,(IsBlank('REQUEST DATE') && ProjectComboBox.Selected.Title in Project )),'Room No.',Ascending)
```

But once replace with a variable as below not fetching the right data as it treats variable as a value

```
Sort(Filter(Install,(IsBlank("'" & UpdateTypeComboBox.SelectedItem.UpdateType & "'") && ProjectComboBox.Selected.Title in Project )),'Room No.',Ascending)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a variable and is actually a value. You may need to use a

UpdateContext({RequestDate: Value}) command or a Set(RequestDate,"")

Are you using a button to fetch the data first if so you may need to select the data first and then feed it into the variable